# How to Combine two .Pem files using Terminal in Mac?

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, terminal, pem

I am trying to combine two .pem files using Terminal

**admins-Mac-2:desktop admin$ $ cat certificates.pem Certificates-dev-certi.pem > cf.pem**

but it shows **-bash: $: command not found**

how to solve this?

Comment: There are two `$` signs in the command, remove one.

Comment: I have Solve this . . By remove "$" before cat